# obtain words from a string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this formula in a javascript string:

```
var testString = '(var01+var02+var03)/3';
```

I would like to know which is the best way to obtain the following result in a array:

```
['var01', 'var02', 'var03']
```

Comment: Are they meant to be variables or strings in that array?

Comment: Your formula won't change ever ?

Comment: Do you wand to extract only variable names from your string?

Comment: They are meant to be strings in that array.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression to match word characters:

```js
var testString = '(var01+var02+var03)/3';
var result = testString.match(/[a-z]\w*/gi);
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

The `g` modifier makes it return an array of all matches.